# Multiple inputs for a lookup transformation (ssis)

Tags: input, ssis, etl, lookup

Is possible to configure a Lookup Transformation in order to receive more than one input?
I tried a Multicast and diferent other ways to build my ETL and after that I think the only way to complete it is configuring the second output

Answer (score 0):

the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation) says no:

> The Lookup transformation has the following inputs and outputs:
>
> Input.
>
> Match output. The match output handles the rows in the transformation
>   input that match at least one entry in the reference dataset.
>
> No Match output. The no match output handles rows in the input that do
>   not match at least one entry in the reference dataset. If you
>   configure the Lookup transformation to treat the rows without matching
>   entries as errors, the rows are redirected to the error output.
>   Otherwise, the transformation would redirect those rows to the no
>   match output.
>
> Error output.

Only one input.